# Java 2D array will not give total

Tags: java, arrays

How do I bring in the methods to get the desired result. I need to get the sum of all numbers and get the highest number in a specified row and the total in the specified column. I also nee to display the 2D Array and build it using random numbers. I believe overall my code is good for each just need to integrate it all together any hint?

Here is my code thus far:

import java.util.*;

public class 2darray {

```
public static int rows=0;
public static int columns=0;
```

//couldn't get it to work but was running out of time before I needed to submit.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int[][] array= new int[rows][columns];



    DisplayArray(array);


    System.out.println("Total of all numbers : " + GetTotal(array));
    System.out.println("Highest in row 2: " + GetHighestInRow(array, 2));
    System.out.println("Column 3 total: " + GetColumnTotal(array, 3));

}

public static void DisplayArray(int[] [] array){


    // this is to display 2D array but couldn't get it to pass into the main

   Random r = new Random();


    int rows = 5;
    int columns=5;

    int [][] ranNums= new int [rows][columns];

    for(int row = 0; row < ranNums.length; row++){
        for(int col =0; col < ranNums[row].length; col++){

            ranNums[row][col]=r.nextInt(20);

        }
    }
    for (int i= 0; i< ranNums.length; i++){// makes the grid
        for (int j=0; j < ranNums[i].length; j++){

            System.out.print(ranNums[i][j] +" ");//prints only 

        }

        System.out.println();

    }

}

public static int GetTotal (int[] []array){
    int total=0;
    int rows=0;
    int columns=0;

    for (int i = 0; i< rows; i++){//increment through the columns and rows
        for (int j=0; j < columns; j++){
            total+=array[i][j]; //we add the to get total
        }
    }
    return total;

}

public static int GetHighestInRow(int [] []array, int sub){//sub is to specify which row

    int columns=0;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++){//increments through the selected row to find highest integer
        if(array[sub][i]>max){
            max = array[sub][i];

        }
    }
    return max;
}

public static int GetColumnTotal (int[] [] array, int sub){//sub is to select column you want total
    int total=0;
    int rows=0;


    for (int i =0; i< rows; i++){
        total+= array[i][sub];
    }
    return total;
}
```

}

**Okay after making some changes listed below this is what I have:**

import java.util.*;

public class 2darray {

```
public static int rows=0;
public static int columns=0;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Random r = new Random();

    int[][] array= new int[rows][columns];

     array [rows][columns]= r.nextInt(10);

    DisplayArray(array);

    System.out.println("Total of all numbers : " + GetTotal(array));
    System.out.println("Highest in row 2: " + GetHighestInRow(array, 2));
    System.out.println("Column 3 total: " + GetColumnTotal(array, 3));

}

public static void DisplayArray(int[] [] array){


    // this is to display 2D array but couldn't get it to pass into the main

//   Random r = new Random();


     rows = 0;
     columns=0;

    int [][] ranNums= new int [rows][columns];

    for(int row = 0; row < ranNums.length; row++){
        for(int col =0; col < ranNums[row].length; col++){

        //  ranNums[row][col]=r.nextInt(20);

        }
    }
    for (int i= 0; i< ranNums.length; i++){// makes the grid
        for (int j=0; j < ranNums[i].length; j++){

            System.out.print(ranNums[i][j] +" ");

        }

        System.out.println();

    }

}

public static int GetTotal (int[] []array){
    int total=0;
     rows=0;
    columns=0;

    for (int i = 0; i< array.length; i++)       
    { int [] thisRow = array [i];
        for (int j=0; j < thisRow.length; j++){
            total+=thisRow[j]; //we add the to get total
        }
    }
    return total;

}

public static int GetHighestInRow(int [] []array, int sub){//sub is to specify which row

    columns=0;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++){//increments through the selected row to find highest integer
        if(array[sub][i]>max){
            max = array[sub][i];

        }
    }
    return max;
}

public static int GetColumnTotal (int[] [] array, int sub){//sub is to select column you want total
    int total=0;
        rows=0;


    for (int i =0; i< rows; i++){
        total+= array[i][sub];//we add the integers in the column to get total
    }
    return total;
}
```

}

Comment: you have several definitions of rows/columns variables and all they have different values, usually 0, this is wrong, remove all of them and use only `public static int..` ones with non zero values

Comment: What are you asking for here? Why are you populating ranNums, where do you populate `array`?

Comment: This was a homework assignment I had to turn in last night..even though it was wrong I had to submit something..so now I am just trying to fix it for myself to learn.

Comment: I thought I was populating the array in the DisplayArray method. I could figure out how to integrate the rest of the code to total all the numbers and the other information needed.

Comment: Since each method is separate i'm not really sure on how to call them so they see the array filled in DisplayArray?

Answer (score 1):

This is the mistake:

```
int rows=0;
int columns=0;

for (int i = 0; i< rows; i++){//increment through the columns and rows
    for (int j=0; j < columns; j++) {
```

The two loops are empty, because `rows` and `columns` are both 0. The same mistake is repeated in your other methods as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're never setting the values of `rows` and `columns` beyond 0. Change this code to:

```
public static int GetTotal (int[] []array){
    int total=0;
    int rows=0;
    int columns=0;

    for (int i = 0; i< array.length; i++){//increment through the columns and rows
        int[] thisRow = array[i];
        for (int j=0; j < thisRow.length; j++){
            total+=thisRow[j]; //we add the to get total
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: So I // out the random r statement in DisplayArray and brought it into the main and changes the code in GetTotal to the above code. I could generate a number grid but now I get an out of bounds exception. Here is